# ADB device list doesn't show phone

Tags: android, adb

I've recently installed `adb` and `fastboot`:

```
apt-get install android-tools-adb android-tools-fastboot
```

After the installation finished, I connected my device and ran the following command:

```
$ adb devices
List of devices attached
```

I've enabled debugging in the phone settings.

I think am doing it wrong-- I don't know. Please explain me the correct process.

Using Ubuntu 16.01. Device: [Yu Yuphoria](http://web.archive.org/web/20161224224917/https://wiki.cyanogenmod.org/w/Lettuce_Info)

Update edit:

After all the frustrating attempts It's still not detected in `adb`.
However in `fastboot` mode, adding the vendor id command for my device, `fastboot -i 0x2a96 devices` as found mentioned [here](http://web.archive.org/web/20161224224917/https://wiki.cyanogenmod.org/w/Lettuce_Info) works

```
fastboot -i 0x2a96 devices
```

returned

```
7dd91912        fastboot
```

Other commands in `fastboot` mode, as instructed in the same page mentioned above, works too when vendor id command option was added.

Comment: Have you already authorized the computer's RSA key?

Comment: Am a total newbee - can you please explain? Thanks.

Comment: When you enable USB debugging in the phone, then attach it via USB, you should get a prompt asking if you want to allow the PC to debug the phone, and it will show you the PC's RSA key to identify it.

Comment: I didn't get any such prompt when I attached my phone to the computer.

Comment: Actually, I just tried going through the setup, and before giving the PC authorization, running `adb devices` had the phone listed as "offline", but it was there.

Comment: Shot in the dark: if you have the phone connected into a USB3 port, try connecting it via USB2 instead.

Comment: Lastly, you might consider asking this question on https://android.stackexchange.com/ as well

Comment: Is the phone listed in the output of `lsusb`?

Comment: Yes the phone is listed in lssub. The phone is running CyanogenOS. The listed specs shows usb 2.0 It's not detected in fastboot mode either.

Comment: Glad you got it working.

Comment: How did you find the "vendor ID"?

Comment: @Teekin see if this helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10086464/how-to-get-vendor-id-of-an-android-powered-device-via-adb

Comment: Nothing helped. I already turned on debug. Sometimes it just won't list the device anymore on Ubuntu until I restart the machine. USB cable is good otherwise I could not make it work before.

Comment: If nothing helps then in Developer Options, click button to revoke all the USB debugging permission, then reconnect and you should see RSA question whether this PC is allowed to connect.

Comment: Try using a USB2.0 port instead of a USB3.0 port.

Comment: This is the **[CANONICAL answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/144967/110742)** to this question.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Finally got the device detected in `adb` under `adb devices` command by restarting adb server with root privilege as mentioned [here](http://web.archive.org/web/20161224201941/https://wiki.cyanogenmod.org/w/Install_CM_for_lettuce) in the **Troubleshooting `adb`** section.

```
sudo adb kill-server
sudo adb start-server
```

After this `adb devices` returned

```
7dd91912      unauthorized
```

with a prompt on device for RSA authorize. After authorizing

`adb devices` now returns

```
72291912      device
```

Comment: also carefully check that debugging via USB is on

Comment: When these steps are not enough, [check out this more complete answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/144967/251697).

Comment: Also note that it might be necessary to unplug and plug the USB again. And if you don't get the initial authorization prompt on your phone, it won't work.

Comment: -1 to this answer, just adds noise. Just check, perfect answer: https://android.stackexchange.com/a/144967/110742

There's no need to repeat everything, considering this is a very requested issue and there's dozens of questions about it.

Comment: Sometimes it's the cable that does not work, even if it can charge... **Try a different cable!**

Answer (score 20):

You installed the `adb` program correctly.  The Android Debugging isn't activated by default.  The activation option is hidden.  You'll have to reveal it with these steps:

```
Goto Settings -> About phone -> (scroll to) Build number ->
 (Tap on it about 7 times) -> (You should get a notice
 You have enabled the development settings)
```

Now you will have a new menu item in settings called **Developer options**.

Go into this option and turn on the **USB debugging** option.

Now when you plug in the USB cable to the computer, you'll get the prompt to **Authorize** the connected computer.

After the debugging is turned on you may have to restart the server.  You can do that with these commands:

```
$ adb kill-server
$ adb start-server
```

Comment: I've already turned on the 'USB debugging' option - but not getting any prompt on connecting to the computer

Comment: Also need to add udev rules for your device

Comment: can you please explain how to add the udev rules

Comment: @red_speck When you connect your device, do you get a usb file browser of the content, or the option to view the content?  Also, try starting restarting the adb server with the `kill-server` and `start-server` added to my answer.

Comment: I don't get this clearly "do you get a usb file browser of the content, or the option to view the content?" but if I guess what you mean, I think it's the usb file browser (I can browse through the files of the phone - I've used all three available options to connect USB for my device - MTP, PTP and charge only). I've tried restarting the adb with your said commands.

Comment: You interpreted that part correctly.  Now can you tell me the results of restarting the server then checking the **`adb devices`** command?

Comment: restart output is this: '*daemon not running. starting it now on port 5037 daemon started successfully *'

Comment: That's the correct/default output of restarting the server.  Now that you have restarted the server are you having the same issue as in your question?

Comment: sadly yes :(...

Comment: Try restarting the computer and see if you still have the same issue.

Comment: not good. still the same

Comment: am running the command in the default location i.e pcname@username. Could that be the problem?

Comment: The location doesn't matter.  The key is to have access to the server, which your kill and restart has indicated.  Try turning off debugging on your device and turning it back on.  Then unplug it from your computer and plug it back in.

Comment: tried that, not good. I'll try adding udev rules as mentioned by @Kyle H using tips in this link https://developer.android.com/studio/run/device.html#setting-up

Comment: My answer explains how to add the udev rules.

Comment: This is the **[CANONICAL answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/144967/110742)** to this question.

Answer (score 10):

To set up device detection on Ubuntu Linux:

Using `sudo`, create this file: `/etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules`.

Use this format to add each vendor to the file:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="0bb4", MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev"
```

In this example, the vendor ID is for HTC. The MODE assignment specifies read/write permissions, and GROUP defines which Unix group owns the device node.

If you do not know your vendor ID, you can get this from `lsusb`, it is the string after ID. If `lsusb` doesn't report your device, try checking `grep USB /var/log/kern.log | less` for vendor ID (for example, a line `New USB device found, idVendor=1bbb, idProduct=0167`).

Once you have created/updated the `51-android.rules` file, execute:

```
sudo chmod a+r /etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules
```

Then restart udev with `sudo service udev restart` or `sudo /etc/init.d/udev restart`

Comment: I did all this, (vendor id for my device 2a96) and also created adb_usb.ini file in .android from this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31624721/adb-and-android-studio-not-detecting-yuphoria)

Comment: To help others - the vendor ID is the first 4 characters  i.e. ID 18d1:4ee7  vendor ID is 18d1   Also - You may think it has not worked but it took a minute after restarting the server before my phone was detected.     And finally, I found a list of vendor codes here -. https://gist.github.com/jdamcd/6054951

Comment: The best way to detect the vendor ID is to run `lsusb` _twice_ : with and without the mobile phone connected and then compare what's missing.

Comment: This is the **[CANONICAL answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/144967/110742)** to this question.

Answer (score 8):

Gilberto Albino gave me a clue.
Nobody tells you that some usb cables are only good for charging devices, not for transferring data.  You have to figure out which you have for yourself.
I think the charge-only cables are thinner.

Comment: This is the **[CANONICAL answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/144967/110742)** to this question.

Answer (score 7):

Make sure you have a good USB cable and are plugged into a good port.  This was always the problem I experience when using ADB and fastboot. Also make sure you update and have the latest ADB drivers.

Comment: ADB drivers? Aren't those only for Windows?

Comment: Agreed, after an entire day spent getting frustrated with my computer and phone, it turned out that the cable was the reason they weren't talking.

Comment: This is the **[CANONICAL answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/144967/110742)** to this question.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem, and after trying all voodoos available on the internet, I found out by myself that the device is only recognizable by the vendor USB cable that accompanies the device.

Comment: *rolling eyes emoji*

Comment: not true. This is the **[CANONICAL answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/144967/110742)** to this question.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not yet sure why this happens, but with my test device, it's only recognized if I accept *temporarily* the debugging request. If I check the "always allow from this computer" it will vanish from `adb devices`.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I solved the problem **changing the USB cable**.

It is a surprise, but I noted device not showing windows after USB connection and just a message "**connected for charge**". The device connect only for energy charge. The device not was showing the device folder in computer too. I changed the cable and the problem dissappear instantaneously. I use Debian (Linux).

Answer (score -1):

#### Enable USB debugging on the device

This is done in *Settings › Development*. If you don't have that entry in your settings menu, go to *Settings › About*, scroll to the "Build number", and hammer it like a monkey until your device congratulates you having become a developer. Go back to the main page of the *Settings* menu, and close to the bottom you should see the "Development" (or "Developers") settings now. Enter it, and enable *USB Debugging* here.

#### Identify the device

First we need to know how the device identifies on the USB bus. For that, with the Android device **NOT** connected, grab a shell and run the command `lsusb`. Then connect the device and run the command again. Spot the new line. For the *Wileyfox Swift* this is a "nameless device":

```
Bus 004 Device 003: ID 2970:2282
```

#### Setting up the rules for ADB

We now need the numbers at the end of the above line: `2970:2282`. These specify the vendor (2970) and the device itself (2282). Having those details, we need a **root** shell on our Linux machine to edit (or create, if it doesn't yet exist) the `/etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules` file. In there, add a line for your device. Following example line shows how it looks for the *Wileyfox Swift:¹*

```
SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="2970", ATTRS{idProduct}=="2282", MODE="0666" GROUP="androiddev", SYMLINK+="android%n"
```

If you have a different device, replace the vendor and product IDs with what you've found above when running `lsusb`. A short explanation of the line:

- `SUBSYSTEMS=="usb"`: obviously this rule is for USB only ;)
- `ATTRS{idVendor}=="2970"`: the vendor ID of the device this rule is for
- `ATTRS{idProduct}=="2282"`: the device ID
- `MODE="0666"`: permissions the device node shall get. `0666` is quite lax, giving every user on your system read and write permission – so if you're concerned, you might try replacing that with a `0660` (giving only owner and group read-write, and deny everything to others).
- `GROUP="androiddev"`: which group the device node should belong to. This should be a group the users intended to work with the device belong to.
- `SYMLINK+="android%n"`: just to give the node a nice name, so you can find it easier in `/dev` (in my case, it later showed up there as `/dev/android5`)

That rule entered in `/etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules`, we must tell `udev` to make use of it. Safest way (next to a reboot ;) is restarting the `udev` service. Depending on your Linux distro, this can be done either via `service udev restart` or `/etc/init.d/udev restart`.

Done that, leave the root shell. Disconnect and reconnect your Android device, try `adb devices` again. Most devices showed up now, but not the *Wileyfox Swift* – which obviously wants some extra cuddles. If you're in that situation, open (or create if it doesn't exist) the file `~/.android/adb_usb.ini` and add a single line to it, naming the vendor you've found out with `lsusb` above; for the *Swift* that would be `0x2970` (yupp, here you need to prefix it by `0x` to point out it's a hexadecimal number). Then restart the ADB server: `adb kill-server && adb start-server`. Disconnect and reconnect the device again. Now `adb devices` should see it.

#### Connecting the device

You might have noticed `adb devices` told you something like `0123456789ABCDEF  unauthorized`. That's OK and for your (devices) safety: your computer must be authorized first to be able to access the device. So simply issue `adb shell` now – which will be quit with an `error: device unauthorized. Please check the confirmation dialog on your device.` Follow that advice (optionally mark the check-box to permanently authorize your computer), and you're done: Now you can use [adb](/questions/tagged/adb) to access your device.

---

#### Updates:

¹ Note that in later Linux versions, syntax for the UDEV rules has slightly changed, as e.g. [jcomeau_ictx](/users/65028/jcomeau-ictx) pointed out in his comment. For the values we found above that would be:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="2970", ATTR{idProduct}=="2282", MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev", SYMLINK+="android%n"
```

Two differences: it's now `SUBSYSTEM` (no plural), and the group has changed from `androiddev` to `plugdev` (the former does not exist on recent systems, the latter does and usually is assigned at least to the first user).

Additionally, you might need to add the vendorID to your `~/.android/adb_usb.ini` (one ID per line, in hex notation):

```
# ANDROID 3RD PARTY USB VENDOR ID LIST
# 1 USB VENDOR ID PER LINE.
0x2970
```

[Source](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/144966/how-do-i-get-my-device-detected-by-adb-on-linux)