# ADB finds no devices and MTP does not work

Tags: usb, android, udev

Running Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, I have attempted to get ADB working with an Android 7.1.1 Wileyfox Swift phone. Running `adb devices` shows no results:

```
$ adb devices
* daemon not running. starting it now on port 5037 *
* daemon started successfully *
List of devices attached
```

Some basics I've tried:

- Multiple USB cables and multiple ports
- Developer mode is on
- USB Debugging is turned on
- I have tried setting USB mode to Charging, PTP, and MTP
- Restarting the `adb server`, and attempting to run it as root.

lsusb shows my phone:

```
$ lsusb
Bus 001 Device 013: ID 2970:2282
```

I have appropriate udev rules (NB I found the second rule at https://compuitusa.com/mounting-the-android-phone-in-ubuntu-16-04/):

```
$ cat /etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="2970", ATTR{idProduct}=="2282", MODE="0666"
$ cat /etc/udev/rules.d/52-mtp.rules
ATTR{idVendor}="2970", ATTR{idProduct}=="2282", SYMLINK+="libmtp-%k", ENV{ID_MTP_DEVICE}="1", ENV{ID_MEDIA_PLAYER}="1"
```

The permissions setup by udev look OK:

```
$ ls -lah /dev/bus/usb/001/013
crw-rw-rw-+ 1 root root 189, 12 Aug 29 06:56 /dev/bus/usb/001/013
```

The phone shows up using `dmesg`:

```
[  672.881607] usb 1-2: new high-speed USB device number 13 using xhci_hcd
[  673.011350] usb 1-2: New USB device found, idVendor=2970, idProduct=2282
[  673.011364] usb 1-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[  673.011371] usb 1-2: Product: Wileyfox Swift
[  673.011378] usb 1-2: Manufacturer: Wileyfox
[  673.011384] usb 1-2: SerialNumber: e81ed488
```

A udevadm test looks Ok:

```
$ udevadm info -q all -n /dev/bus/usb/001/013
P: /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-2
N: bus/usb/001/013
S: libmtp-1-2
E: BUSNUM=001
E: DEVLINKS=/dev/libmtp-1-2
E: DEVNAME=/dev/bus/usb/001/013
E: DEVNUM=013
E: DEVPATH=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-2
E: DEVTYPE=usb_device
E: DRIVER=usb
E: ID_BUS=usb
E: ID_FOR_SEAT=usb-pci-0000_00_14_0-usb-0_2
E: ID_MEDIA_PLAYER=1
E: ID_MODEL=Wileyfox_Swift
E: ID_MODEL_ENC=Wileyfox\x20Swift
E: ID_MODEL_ID=2282
E: ID_MTP_DEVICE=1
E: ID_PATH=pci-0000:00:14.0-usb-0:2
E: ID_PATH_TAG=pci-0000_00_14_0-usb-0_2
E: ID_REVISION=0310
E: ID_SERIAL=Wileyfox_Wileyfox_Swift_e81ed488
E: ID_SERIAL_SHORT=e81ed488
E: ID_USB_INTERFACES=:ffff00:ff4201:
E: ID_VENDOR=Wileyfox
E: ID_VENDOR_ENC=Wileyfox
E: ID_VENDOR_ID=2970
E: MAJOR=189
E: MINOR=12
E: PRODUCT=2970/2282/310
E: SUBSYSTEM=usb
E: TAGS=:seat:uaccess:
E: TYPE=0/0/0
E: USEC_INITIALIZED=673329989
```

The phone is displayed as a Unity launcher. However, clicking on the launcher sometimes brings up a pop up message ‘Unable to mount Android Device‘ but does nothing else. Running Nautilus shows the phone as an entry under Computer: clicking the phone's entry does nothing. I've also tried setting the phone's usb parameters to Charging and PTP rather than MTP with no success for `adb devices` or to see the phone's files. Any ideas how to get ADB to find the phone and how to see the phone's files in Nautilus?

Comment: The question "How can I stop 'Unable to mount Android Device' messages from popping up?" goes part way to addressing this question. For me, that thread did not help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ADB device list doesn't show phone](https://askubuntu.com/questions/863587/adb-device-list-doesnt-show-phone)