# ADB Ubuntu 18.04 Does Nothing

Tags: 18.04, android, adb

I am trying to use adb on Ubuntu 18.04, but when I use any command, other than "adb version" it drops to the next line and does nothing. I have tried with and without sodo.

```
Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.39
Version 1:8.1.0+r23-5~18.04
Installed as /usr/lib/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb
```

Has anyone had this issue?

Comment: Have you done this: https://askubuntu.com/a/863624/243321

Comment: It's not that Linux doesn't see the device. Udev works as it should and connects the Android. ADB does not work, at all. Any command, except "version" does nothing, with the device plugged or unplugged. For instance, `adb start-server` or `adb get-state` just drops to a blank line and never completes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it. Apparently Traccar server was still installed on this dev system and uses the same port ADB uses. Removing Traccar fixed the issue.

Description of the issue is found in detail, here: [ADB hangs when trying to start or stop server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17116121/adb-hangs-when-trying-to-start-or-stop-server)